# EJB Invocation failed on component

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, java-ee-6

The following Exception occurs when i inject the UserRepository Interface in to the controller:

```
EJB Invocation failed on component UserRepositoryMock for method public abstract java.util.List com.test.repository.IRepository.all(): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
```

I'm not sure, maybe the inheritance hierachy could be a problem:

IRepository is implemented by IUserRepository. Then I've an abstract class AbstractRepository that also implements IRepository.
The UserRepositoryMock extends AbstractRepository  and implements the IUserRepository Interface.

In Code:

```
@Singleton
@Alternative
public class UserRepositoryMock extends AbstractRepository<IUser> implements IUserRepository {
@EJB
private IUserFactory userFactory;
public UserRepositoryMock(){
    userFactory.generateFirstUser()
}
}
```

AbstractRepository

```
@Singleton
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends IBO> implements IRepository<T> {
@Override
public List<T> all(){....}
}
```

IUserRepository:

```
public interface IUserRepository extends IRepository<IUser>{
...
}
```

Other injections working fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change this:

```
public UserRepositoryMock(){
    userFactory.generateFirstUser();
}
```

to something like:

```
@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    userFactory.generateFirstUser();
}
```